# A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque

Tags: android

Error

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vigneshbaskar.concavechat/com.example.vigneshbaskar.concavechat.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque

java

```
package com.example.vigneshbaskar.concavechat;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.vigneshbaskar.concavechat.MainActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vigneshbaskar.concavechat">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.example.vigneshbaskar.concavechat.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/FullTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Show the full logcat, please

Comment: Also, post the definition of `FullTheme`, including its colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use Alpha in primary color just make your primary color opaque. Go to `res>values>colors`  and replace your color primary code with this `#3F51B5` (blue);

Answer (score 0):

In `styles/FullTheme.xml`, remove the alpha channel from your `@color/primaryColor` definition. The first two digits of a color are its alpha channel, e.g. #**CC**FF0000. Remove the `CC` (in this example).