# Quiz module is running on android emulator but not on android device

Tags: java, android

Quiz module is running on android emulator but not on android device. Im running android nougat and api 27 on the emulator. Here is the build.gradle. The only thins is that when i open the quiz module on my emulator it runs well. But in my device it closes the app.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.stitaft.datarial"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    // Glide image library
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms:view-pager-transforms:1.2.32@aar'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:parent:3.8.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is the run log. But there is no logcat error i don't know why.

```
02/13 02:28:52: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\Timoooow\Desktop\fix\DATARIAL\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.stitaft.datarial
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.stitaft.datarial"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.stitaft.datarial
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.stitaft.datarial/com.example.stitaft.datarial.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 8210 on device asus-p01v-FBNPFP015860
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 42497(1815KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 19% free, 4MB/5MB, paused 4.994ms total 107.476ms
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11020
I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:2 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:0
I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.flags
W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
V/FA: Collection enabled
V/FA: App package, google app id: com.example.stitaft.datarial, 1:763239624265:android:6f1303d43fb6228a
I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
        adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.stitaft.datarial
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
V/FA: Persisting first open: 1518459857646
V/FA: State of service unknown
V/FA: Checking service availability
V/FA: Service available
V/FA: Setting useService: true
V/FA: Using measurement service
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.crash:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.crash:10
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.crash, version >= 10
V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.example.stitaft.datarial
V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = /data/data/flipfont/app_fonts/Syndor#Syndor
V/FA: Using measurement service
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 18.543ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5301(442KB) AllocSpace objects, 9(144KB) LOS objects, 40% free, 4MB/7MB, paused 21.963ms total 135.355ms
I/art: DexFile_isDexOptNeeded failed to open oat file '/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@data@com.google.android.gms@app_chimera@m@0000003c@DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodlmp_alldpi_release.apk@classes.dex' for file location '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000003c/DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodlmp_alldpi_release.apk': Failed to open oat filename for reading: No such file or directory
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.stitaft.datarial/com.example.stitaft.datarial.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2378)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5255)
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:838)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
                      Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque
                         at android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription.<init>(ActivityManager.java:538)
                         at android.app.Activity.onApplyThemeResource(Activity.java:3719)
                         at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:140)
                         at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:85)
                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setTheme(AppCompatActivity.java:89)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2378) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5255) 
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:838) 
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651) 
I/FirebaseCrashApiImpl: FirebaseCrashApiImpl created by ClassLoader ae[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000003c/DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodlmp_alldpi_release.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]
I/FirebaseCrash: FirebaseCrash reporting loaded - com.google.android.gms.internal.ml@1b3c2d41
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:2 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:0
I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.flags
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
I/FirebaseCrashApiImpl: FirebaseCrash reporting API initialized
E/UncaughtException: Ouch! My own exception handler threw an exception.
                     java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:176)
                         at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash$zzc.uncaughtException(Unknown Source)
                         at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                         at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.stitaft.datarial, PID: 8210
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.stitaft.datarial/com.example.stitaft.datarial.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2378)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5255)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:838)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
                   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque
                      at android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription.<init>(ActivityManager.java:538)
                      at android.app.Activity.onApplyThemeResource(Activity.java:3719)
                      at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:140)
                      at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:85)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setTheme(AppCompatActivity.java:89)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2378) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5255) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:838) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8210 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Could you attach your error log ?

Comment: @Abhishekkumar I added the run log. Thanks for helping

Comment: @Abhishekkumar also on lower versions of android line marshmallow the app wont open

Comment: Are you running the dubbing app  by android studio or by other source?

Comment: @Abhishekkumar im running it on android studio.

Comment: seems to be multidex related issue, did u enable multidex support in Application class?

Comment: In android studio , click on logcat then select verbose to error than check log error will show to you @TreacherousLaroya

Comment: @lib4 i think it is not enabled yet. how can i enable it?

Comment: In application class do this  @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

Comment: @lib4 i checked it and it is enabled multiDexEnabled true

Comment: could u post your application class

Comment: @lib4 i think i cant see my application class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166809/5-1-crash-a-taskdescriptions-primary-color-should-be-opaque, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438588/a-taskdescriptions-primary-color-should-be-opaque